# Read an undefined number of columns in Python and plot data with matplotlib

Tags: python, file, input, matplotlib

In a python code I do the following:

```
x1=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]
y3=[]
y4=[]



for line in res_file_1.readlines():
    ll=string.split(line)
    x1.append(float(ll[0]))
    y1.append(float(ll[1]))
    y2.append(float(ll[2]))
    y3.append(float(ll[3]))
    y4.append(float(ll[4]))
```

So it reads 4 columns of a file and stores values in the different "y" arrays. I wonder how could I do this more general, i.e., when I do not know whether the input file will contain 4, or 16 or 2000 columns

UPDATE:

Later I need to plot data with matplotlib, so I usually do:

```
ax.plot(x1,y1,'ks',color='red')
ax.plot(x1,y2,'ks',color='green')
ax.plot(x1,y3,'ks',color='blue')
```

How can I do the plot for the undefined number of columns (and colors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a data file `input.csv` like this:

```
x1, y1, y2, y3, y4
A, 3, 6, 7, 1
B, 4, 5, 9, 0
X, 7, 2, 8, 5
C, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

With [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', delimiter=',', index_col='x1')
df.plot(marker='s')
plt.show()
```

and you will get this plot:

[image]

Comment: ok, and what can you do in pandas when the x1 column is not filled with numbers but just letters? and the rest of y columns are numbers

Comment: Sorry, I ran exactly that code on Mac OS X 10.7, there is no error but no output at all. I installed pandas using macports and run it using python2.7 plot.py, why the error?

Comment: I think you should ask this as another question or open an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues). It should work on MAC OS (I'm on linux).

Comment: Sorry, I was running this in `ipython --pylab`. Added the show call.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = list(izip_longest(*[x.split() for x in f]))
```

This creates a list of tuples, where each tuple contains values from one column.

Answer (score 2):

use `numpy.genfromtxt` and read the columns into `recarray`s, and when you want to loop through the columns for plotting, use `recarray.dtype.names` to retrieve each column.

Comment: @flow paste me the data file (a few lines would be fine) and I can come up with some code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary, where they keys are x and the values are lists of y's:

```
data = {}
for line in res_file_1.readlines():
    ll = line.split()
    data[ll[0]] = ll[1:]
```

Comment: this is assuming that ordering of rows isn't important

Comment: how can one access the different elements, for instance, for x=1, the element of column3? I am trying to do it

Comment: data[1][2] will give you the value of x=1, y=3